# Guava Table alternative

Tags: java, guava

We have partitioned database and data of each user is stored at specific server.

My use case is fairly simple:

- Users has conversations.
- For one conversation there is two representing record at database (Each user has its own conversation record).

In case a delete operation for user, I would like to delete all conversations between each user. That is to say, I need to delete all conversations related to user in each server. I desperately need grouped data per server.

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Set<Integer>> setPerUser = HashBasedTable.create();

for(Conversation conversation : conversations) {
   Integer serverIndex = getServerForUser(conversation);
   Integer userId = conversation.getUserId();
   Set<Integer> uci = setPerUser.get(serverIndex, userId);
   if(uci == null) {
      uci = Sets.newHashSet();
      setPerUser.put(serverIndex, userId, uci);
   }
   uci.add(conversation.id);
}
```

At the beginning I thought that each row can represent servers and column users.
It seems that Table data structure is not suitable for this case. In this case Table is representing is too sparse data. Although Table can represent `M x N` data, I have just `M + N` data.

What is the correct data structure to represent this data?

Edit:

Of course Table can handle this situation but I am not sure about whether it is fitting or not for this problem. What make me think about Table is having row and column methods which implies a complicated algorithm. In my use case columns has one value which means each user has an only one corresponding server but each row has multiple values mean each server has multiple users.

Comment: Why do you think that `Table` can't handle it? There are multiple implementations and e.g. `HashBasedTable` is suitable for sparse tables. There's some overhead, which you might be able to eliminate with a handmade implementation, but is it worth it?

Comment: @maaartinus edited. Could you expand eliminating handmade overhead. It will really help me. Thanks

Comment: Look at the answer by Sean Patrick Floyd, this is about what I'd do. However, I don't understand why you want to use server in your data structure???

Comment: I want to call a web service to delete all unnecessary conversations. Instead of thousands times, It is better to call just one time for each server. That is to say, this data structure is a temporary storage for splitting data according to our partitioned databases.

Comment: This makes sense... but then: 1. Initially, ignore the server and compute the set of all to be deleted conversations. 2. Split this set by server. Alternatively, you can combine both steps by using `Multiset<Server, Conversation>`. Anyway, a `Table` like above makes no more sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using an existing data structure is not going to work for your use case.

Instead, you should design Objects corresponding to your data:

```
public Class User{
  int id;
  Set<Conversation> conversations;
}

public class Conversation{
  int id;
  Set<User> parcipitants;
}
```

(Getters, Setters, equals() / hashCode() ommitted in both cases)

Now keep two maps to lookup users and conversations:

```
private Map<Integer, Conversation> conversationsById;
private Map<Integer, User> usersById;
```

Write methods like `getOrCreateConversation(Integer id)` and `getOrCreateUser(Integer id)` etc.

Also, you should think about using a persistence technology like JPA or Hibernate, because these are excellent at maintaining such relationships.